# align text on floating img

Tags: css, alignment

how do I align the text and the image using float? I marked the text in red which should correspond with the floating image. Somehow I can't manage to get the circled text into the correct position.

[image]

my css for the images:

```
   .floatinglleft{
     margin-right: 16px; float: left;
}   

  .floatingright{
     margin-left:  16px; float: right;
}
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: you could float a figure element with a figcaption inside and centered

Comment: Add a div within the floating left div, and centre its text.

Answer (score 1):

see below code

```css
.thumb {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
.desc{
  float:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <img class="floatright" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*kOuvkQUrByiaqZYTZFJz4g.png" alt="foo"/>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor
  </p>
</div>
<div class="desc">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu quo duis aperiam, id has ferri placerat suavitate. Vis oratio bonorum ei, discere delicata pro no. Erant maiestatis et cum. Est iusto veritus et, liber tollit sensibus his eu. Eam cu errem persius.

Sumo accusata eam id. Te expetenda iudicabit delicatissimi ius. Nec ut laoreet argumentum, sed ad erat libris. Vim ullum omnium te. Mel mazim noster delicatissimi no, conceptam philosophia vim ea, vix esse soleat mucius in. Ne quod explicari pri, eam diceret nonumes accumsan id.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu quo duis aperiam, id has ferri placerat suavitate. Vis oratio bonorum ei, discere delicata pro no. Erant maiestatis et cum. Est iusto veritus et, liber tollit sensibus his eu. Eam cu errem persius.

Sumo accusata eam id. Te expetenda iudicabit delicatissimi ius. Nec ut laoreet argumentum, sed ad erat libris. Vim ullum omnium te. Mel mazim noster delicatissimi no, conceptam philosophia vim ea, vix esse soleat mucius in. Ne quod explicari pri, eam diceret nonumes accumsan id.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu quo duis aperiam, id has ferri placerat suavitate. Vis oratio bonorum ei, discere delicata pro no. Erant maiestatis et cum. Est iusto veritus et, liber tollit sensibus his eu. Eam cu errem persius.

Sumo accusata eam id. Te expetenda iudicabit delicatissimi ius. Nec ut laoreet argumentum, sed ad erat libris. Vim ullum omnium te. Mel mazim noster delicatissimi no, conceptam philosophia vim ea, vix esse soleat mucius in. Ne quod explicari pri, eam diceret nonumes accumsan id.


 </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: @DjCool if its works for you then you should mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution I made that you could adapt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        Title
    </title>
    <style>
        img {
            width: 200px;
        }

        .picture-float-left {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="picture-float-left">
        <img src="picture.jpg" alt="sample picture">
        <div>Caption under picture</div>
    </div>
    <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```